# Why are rails development credentials gitignored by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm generating credentials using the following command:
`rails credentials:edit --environment development`

I notice that rails puts this in the gitignore:
`+/config/credentials/development.key`

I dont understand why, based on the following reasons:

1. The development credential file is encrypted by default, hence harmless to check in as long as the master key isnt checked in.
2. It's essential for a fresh environment setup (eg. on a new dev environment)
3. If the original file is lost, all the data in the dev environment will have to be reseeded.

I'm inclined to check it in but figured, given Chesterton's fence and all, I'm likely missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was confused between the `development.key` and the  `config/credentials/development.yml.enc`. The latter is the encrypted credential file.